# backend access per user status

Tags: login

I need some help!

When a member on my site stops paying, their membership expires, or they cancel, the plugin still allows sign in access on wp-login.php, which sends them directly to the back end control panel.

What i need, is for them to be ALLOWED to log in, but, RESTRCICT access to the back end control panel depending upon their "status".   This should make more sense in a second.

information.

Table: wp_pmpro_memberships_users
Field: user_id
Field: status
Data within status field: Canceled, Inactive, Active,
(possibly others, but those are what i see)

field "user_id"   MATCHES "ID" from "wp-users"

So, what i need is,   for wp-login.php to differentiate between "status" levels.

if status = "Active"  redirect to "Dashboard "

else KILL/RESTRICT ALL ACCESS to Dashboard and REDIRECT to "membership page".

at which time, they can renew their membership and re-enable dashboard access.

---

or is there a membership based plugin that does this already?????  I assume not, because, it seems like you have to change core files to accomplish this. Either way, i need this to be 100% automated.

Please help. !!

P.S.  unfortunately, i need working code, not theory. I'm not a great programmer.   I know it's a lot to ask, but, i am in desperate need of assistance in this and can't afford to pay what people are asking to accomplish this.

Comment: PPS   the plugin i am using is  Paid Memberships Pro

Comment: ppps.   most "paid membership" plugins,  restrict access to CONTENT on the front end.   my site needs to restrict or grant CONTENT CREATION ability.   that's the easiest way to explain it.

Comment: This would be somewhat easy but we are dealing with a 3rd party plugin here (which is considered off topic on WPSE).  If it were pure WP, we would check a user's capability and redirect accordingly.  But with this 3rd party plugin, it's impossible to give you a working code without knowing how the plugin handles a user's status mobility.  Unfortunately, I'm not sure anyone can help you on this forum

Comment: There might be an easy solution for you after all... I just remembered a plugin I used once for a client https://wordpress.org/plugins/peters-login-redirect/. You will be able to redirect a user based on his role or capability.  Now I don't know if this is going to play nice with Paid Membership Pro, but you can always try it out!

Comment: Thanks. i'm going to look into the plugin a little further. I just briefly read the overview.   I know what i typed out was overly complicated.  and i understand about the 3rd party plugins.  etc.
 which apparently only complicated matters
but my main concern is...   where do i go in the core wordpress files, to add a script that access the database, looks for the data, and then either does or does not allow access to Dashboard?    The plugin info is somewhat inconsequential, but was necessary for me to explain for the sake of people understanding what i was talking about and why i'm asking.

Comment: OR maybe you were telling me to re-write peter's plugin to make it do this???   :)

Comment: I think i found a workaround with another plugin.. however it's still manual.  i need to automate my site.  

is there anyone out there that wants to make a few bucks that knows this stuff?????????????   i'm sure tons...  LMK before i get flagged or something.   thx

Comment: Well I'm not telling you to rewrite peter's plugin, I think that plugin could do what you want. that is redirect users based on their current role/capability.  Assuming paid membership pro switches the role/capability based on a user current subscription, you would only have to configure a rule for each membership status in peter's plugin. So you would have let's say: if `inactive_status_or_role` user then redirect to your subscription page.  As for WP core functions, like I said, this is done by checking a user capability and role (a lot like peter's plugin do).

Comment: Automating this would depend on how PMP handles  subscriptions (I assume they already have an automation mechanism) so I think it's doable with peter's plugin if you manage to configure each membership status and assign your redirect to those status .  If you still need help on automating this, I invite you to find my contact page on my website (which you can find in my WPSE profile).  We could discuss further in private.

Answer (score 0):

I decided to still provide an answer based on the premise of the title **backend access per user status**

Note this is an explanation to the concept of granting or restricting access based on user statuses (roles or capabilities). So this could or could not be applied directly to your situation since you make use of a third party plugin with it's own logic. But still, I believe it relevant because I'm showing here some fundamental WP access logic which I'm sure your plugin is based in part or in whole upon.

Now for the long explanation!

Basically, what we want to do is

- Check our current user status level ( I would map statuses to capabilities)
- If status is `active` then grant access to dashboard.
- If status is anything other (`pending`, `canceled`, `inactive`, etc) then redirect to signup page
- I'll keep the complexity low for the purpose of this explanation, but we could check for more contexts and apply different rule for each context. Here it's going to be "`active`" and `else`
- The logic of attributing and modifying membership levels to a user will be kept out because this is what the membership plugin does (and is beyond the scope of this explanation). So again, I'll focus on **backend access per user status** assuming that *the status* logic is taking care of by another process.

So WP roles and capabilities offer great flexibility to manage a user's site access and restrictions.

A role is like a container for capabilities and defines the context of a user.

Capabilities are flags on which we can check on to know if an action is permitted or not. For instance `edit_posts` is a WP capability.  Having the check `if( current_user_can( 'edit_posts' ) ){ // Do something  }` will return `true` if the flag for `edit_posts` is set, the we do something, if not, it will fail and we can do something else or bail out.

A role can have 1 or more capabilities, we can add custom capabilities to roles and we can remove capabilities from roles. We could also just toggle the flag which is better in terms of DB query (flag toggle are done at runtime so no DB queries)
We could also make custom roles with core capabilities or our own custom ones.  That is what makes WP so flexible for many use case.

We can add capabilities on the fly for specific user or special contexts with the use of filters.

Back to your membership plugin. I assume the plugin would do a bunch of checks to see if a membership subscription is valid or not. I also assume that you have at least 2 roles available. Let's call them *Active Members* for valid memberships and *Inactive Members* for memberships that are `expired`, `canceled` etc. If you have a user that is not a member yet, he might use WP core role `subscriber` which has no real capabilities except access his/her profile page. Again, I take for granted that the membership plugin would programmatically change the role of a user based on the validation of his membership status. ( Normally this is/should be done by any (good) membership plugin )

Finally, once all that is set, we would have a function that would use the [`current_user_can`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/current_user_can) function and [`user_has_cap`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/user_has_cap) filter and modify the user's access based on is current role. (The current role is based by the plugins verification of membership status)

Here's an example based on what I just layed out.  Our *Active Members* roles should have a capability to `see_premium_content` (or whatever this is for the example) which our *Inactive Members* would not or be set to false. Based on that, we would need 2 functions to check and restrict. It would look something like this.

```
add_action( 'init', 'wpse_backend_access_rules' );
function wpse_backend_access_rules(){

  // check to see if current logged in user can "see_premium_content" add restriction if not by modifying capabilities
  if( ! current_user_can( 'see_premium_content' ) ){
    add_filter( 'user_has_cap', 'inactive_membership_cap_filter', 10, 3 );
  }
}


function inactive_membership_cap_filter( $allcaps, $cap, $args ) {

  // give only permission to access own profile in dashboard.
  // On the profile dashboard, you can output a message inviting to sign up again.
  $allcaps = array(
    'read' => true
  );

  return $allcaps;
}
```

Comment: ohh you beautiful man!  ..   Thanks.  i haven't read this yet, but the fact it's there at all is brilliant.   i appreciate it! ..   will update as needed if needed!

Answer (score 0):

ok cool..   Bynicolas.   If you're still reading,  Here's my breakdown of what i gathered.

I believe you have a good understanding of what i'm trying to accomplish, but i'm going to touch on a few things, to verify that we are both on the same page... myself included.

The logic of the plugin in question, does create memberships at various price levels. it basically allows the user to read various "categories" within posts, or specific member area pages.  which is not at all what i want or need.  However, it accepts money for recurring accts, and it creates/generates Users. 
a second plugin creates roles, role groups, etc, and i can allow specific dashboard content to specific users. by this, i am able to say for example, give a "free membership" user created by the membership plugin,  a specific Role to access "Properties" (as in homes/houses).  or a "corporate membership" can have the roll of "full access" to access properties, land, commercial properties, condos, blah blah".

With that said, neither of the plugins restrict dashboard access once expired.  and since the areas they are paying to access, set by roles, are not external page areas such as posts or specific pages on the public side of the site, that's why i need this restriction.  However, i feel that you have a very good grasp of the concept.

as for bullet point 3, yeah, i understand that there could be multiple potential circumstances depending upon status value, but i am ok with sending them to the signup page regardless of status, aside from "Active". This is something i debated with myself previously, and like you, thought "keep the complexity low".

There's a lot of talk about roles after that, which, is a concept i recently came to fully understand after spending several hours yelling at my monitor while configuring the roles plugin.     However, the roles area of the db isn't where the status is held, its part of the membership plugin. but.... you just said that too.

yeah, it does a ton of checks, an i have 6 roles or role groups. I haven't made a choice on which to use. i think groups. but as mentioned in the second paragraph about access and "status" etc... no need repeating.

now, that's the thing "Again, I take for granted that the membership plugin would programmatically change the role of a user based on the validation of his membership status. ( Normally this is/should be done by any (good) membership plugin )"   The membership plugin, does not assign, create, alter, delegate etc, roles at all.   it only allows access to specific visible site content.   like "you can now access example.com/paid_stuff/free_area" ... that's the problem. i'm trying to make it do something it doesn't do by nature.  i have yet to find a membership plugin that creates user roles/groups, and alters potential access to dashboard elements, and then there's the fact that it most likely wouldn't do things like, "only allow users to see the media they uploaded".  which, my roles plugin does.    that's why this whole thing is a mess. i have to use 3 plugins to accomplish 80-90% of what i need, and will have to manually update all of the customers access, and manually assign roles, etc.   I'm ok with doing the majority of it, but.  I don't want to have to have a calendar on my desktop setting alerts every day for who to check up on and temporarily ban as a user so they can't access because their account lapsed. It's not an expandable solution.

but again, i feel like you get that.

"Finally, once all that is set, we would have a function that would use the current_user_can function and user_has_cap filter and modify the user's access based on is current role. (The current role is based by the plugins verification of membership status)" 
 This part i don't understand, and i don't know if we're on the same page. It may be me, so i'll reiterate. prior to this you said

" Again, I take for granted that the membership plugin would programmatically change the role of a user based on the validation of his membership status. ( Normally this is/should be done by any (good) membership plugin )"   but mine doesn't doesn't.   so is the previous paragraph still valid? or does it now need revision, since the code offered may be based upon that idea?

the final paragraph is where i get lost, given the previous paragraphs.    So basically, i'm getting lost on the "ok, so here's how you'd do it".  lol
 and.. i know this is going to sound ridiculous as well but. what file would i be looking at ?  functions or wp-login to implement said changes?   Also, i have literally never worked with or programmed anything that gathers DB info at runtime. that, is a VERY foreign concept to me.  But it also explains why i have never found any queries in these pages.

however, i think we're getting warmer..    but long story short, you definitely understand the problem. but i don't understand the solution. lol